# Using MessageToByteEncoder as last outbound handler doesn't return anything

Tags: java, netty

I have a pipeline as follows:

```
Preprocessor -> Decoder -> Encoder -> Processor
```

`Preprocessor`, `Decoder` and `Processor` are all `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`. `Encoder` is a `MessageToByteEncoder<CommandResponse>`.

When my request (sent as UDP datagram) is received by the pipeline, it is parsed as `String` by the `Preprocessor`, and the `String` is passed to the `Decoder`. The `Decoder` parses the `String` to create a `Command` object, and passes the resulting object to the `Processor`. The `Processor` processes the `Command` and generates a `CommandResponse` object which is passed to the `Encoder` by calling `ctx.writeAndFlush(commandResponse);`. The `Encoder` encodes the command to a byte array and then to a `ByteBuf` as follows:

```
@Override
protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, CommandResponse msg, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
    //Encode the response
    String responseString;
    .....

    //Convert resulting string to bytes using specified charset
    byte[] bytes = responseString.getBytes(charset);

    //Send bytes
    out.writeBytes(bytes);
}
```

However, nothing is received on the sending side.

I precise I use an `NioDatagramChannel` for the channel and Netty version 4.0.x.

Thanks,
Mickael

Answer (score 0):

I guess the ChannelFuture which was returned by the write call was failed. Check this. Also as you use a NioDatagramChannel you most likely want to convert from CommandResponse to a DatagramPacket. Use a MessageToMessageEncoder for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help Norman! I already this issue in another handler (not an Encoder) and I solved it by writing a DatagramPacket. However, I was able to get the packet's sender and set it as recipient address but I don't know how to get it in the encode method.

Comment: Instead of forwarding a string, can the Preprocessor forward an object containing the string and the sender's address? Include the sender's address in the command objects and you'll have the information when you need it.

Comment: @johnstlr Is it really the way Netty should be used?

Comment: Norman may correct me but, with UDP, I don't see you've got much choice. AIUI Netty doesn't create a new pipeline for each UDP endpoint because there's only one socket receiving all incoming packets. The UDP packet contains all the information about the remote peer. If you drop the datagram packet you lose that information. Maybe it would be better to decode directly to a command object and include the sender's address there - i.e. combine the preprocessor and decoder.